# if ($success), prompt/alert instead of echo. how?

Tags: php, echo, prompt

I'm a total newbie on PHP, but I can change the code a bit to fit my needs.
I have a form that when you send it, it shows a message of success/fail inside the page.
But instead of the message appearing inside the page, I just wanted a **prompt / alert** showing the success/fail message.

So what I have is

```
if ($success){ echo "Sent! Thank you";}
else{  echo "Ops! Try again!";}
```

Any  ideas?
Thank you so much in advance

Comment: What do you mean with "prompt"? Usually you only see prompts on the command line and not on web pages.

Comment: @KingCrunch, wrong, it's just that prompts happen on javascript or html side, which is across the net from php ;-)

Comment: Prompts can only be achieved by JavaScript, assuming that's what you mean

Comment: maybe an ''alert'' ? I'm such a shame on PHP, I'm sorry

Comment: You want display an "Alert Box" or "Some colored box with the message"... If it's true, you must use Javascript (with Ajax Call).

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you might not want what you say you want but…

```
if ($success){ 
    $message = "Sent! Thank you";
} else {
    $message = "Ops! Try again!";
}
?><script>
    prompt(<?php echo json_encode($message); ?>);
</script>
<noscript>
    <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($message); ?></p>
</noscript>
```

Note: Given a string for input, `json_encode` will output a JavaScript string literal that is safe for inclusion in an HTML script element. It will not output JSON.

While the strings themselves don't contain any special characters, it is a good habit to run this sort of XSS protection against anything you output that isn't explicitly HTML/JS/etc.

Comment: Hey Quentin, first of all thank you, here the code shows my message and requests an answer. Also changes the page inside, which I'm trying to avoid. My idea was just any type of confirmation message that didn't change the page from where the form was sent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want somthing better-looking:

```
<?php
   if ($success) {
       $message = "Sent! Thank you.";
   } else {
       $message = "Oops...";
   }
   echo '<div id="message">'.$message.'<div id="close-button"></div></div>';
?>
```

This way you can style your message like you want to (like positioning it absolutely). But you would have to implement the close button in javascript if the div is positioned absolute.

Comment: Hey Jens! Thank you, here the code works just like echo, it's not a popup, seems more like a page with a div inside, with the message. I was looking for something that didn't change the page where the form is. Just a pop-up message of confirmation

Comment: I don't think you will be able not to change the page with php. php is executed on the server and only the output of the php code is delivered to the client. Is there a strong reason for not changing the page?

Comment: Well, my whole code is in one page. When the message appears ''sent! thank you!'' it's on a blank page and everything, including the navigation menu is gone. I could make in frames and keep the menu but there are so many pages to link :( also, I could redirect to another page when it succeed/fails, but I think it would be asking too much in here and I don't even know where to start the code to redirect on success ...

Comment: In php `header("location: http://example.com/some-page.php")` will redirect you. BTW: This is common practise. Create a page for success, another for failure and redirect the user to these pages. This way your php script does not need any output.

Comment: So Jens, when I place header('location: page.htm') it returns an error, I believe I'm placing this on a very wrong way. Should I place this replacing $message = "Sent! Thank you."; ? Thank you and sorry to bother you again

Comment: What error? You are not allowed to produce any output in your php script before using header(). See example from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php)